# How to Find the Integral of Modified Bessel Function of 2nd Type?

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

How can I find a closed form for this integral

\begin{align}
        I_1=\int\limits_{0}^{x_{out}}x^{M+2} K_{M-1}(x)dx, M>0~\text{and}~ x_{out}>0
    \end{align}

Comment: Is it possible to present it in other form. When I use mathematica, it show like \begin{align} 2^{M+1} \Gamma (M+1)-\frac{1}{2} \pi  x_{out}^{M+1} \csc (\pi  M) (-2 I_{-M-1}(x_{out})+x_{out} I_{-M}(x_{out})-2 M I_{M+1}(x_{out})-x_{out} I_{M+2}(x_{out})) \end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^{x_{out}}x^{M+2}K_{M-1}(x)~dx$

$=-\int_0^{x_{out}}x^2~d(x^MK_M(x))$ (according to http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_484.htm)

$=-[x^{M+2}K_M(x)]_0^{x_{out}}+\int_0^{x_{out}}x^MK_M(x)~d(x^2)$

$=-x_{out}^{M+2}K_M(x_{out})+2\int_0^{x_{out}}x^{M+1}K_M(x)~dx$

$=2^{M+1}\Gamma(M+1)-2x_{out}^{M+1}K_{M+1}(x_{out})-x_{out}^{M+2}K_M(x_{out})$ (according to http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_484.htm)

Comment: Many thanks Harry Peter!